# Repeat async task by timer in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, asynchronous, timer, xamarin.forms

i'm new to xamarin.forms development and i'm still having my first steps from the few tutorials that are found on the net.
I have an async task that returns the time from date.jsontest.com
and i have a timer that decrements a text in a label.
i want to put the async task in the timer so that it repeats itself and displays the time on the label however im getting cannot convert async lamba to func

here's my code please help me, thanks

```
static async Task<string> RequestTimeAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var jsonString = await client.GetStringAsync("http://date.jsontest.com/");
            var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
            return jsonObject["time"].Value<string>();
        }
    }


 protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        timeLabel.Text = await RequestTimeAsync();

        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () => { // i want the taks to be put 
//here so that it gets repeated
            var number = float.Parse(button.Text) - 1;
            button.Text = number.ToString();
            return number > 0;
        });

    }
```

Reloading the Content Page in the timer would do the trick, so if anybody can please help me it would be appreciated

Comment: Put the async word in front of your lambda, like this `Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), async () => {` then you can use the await inside your function.

Comment: it gave me error: not all code paths return lambda expression of type func<bool>

Answer (score 17):

You just need to wrap the async method call in a Task.Run(), for example:

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
{
  Task.Run(async () =>
  {
    var time = await RequestTimeAsync();
    // do something with time...
  });
  return true;
});
```

Comment: This is but running on separate thread than UI thread and wont update anything on the UI i believe. And more importantly this creates a new thread with every timer thick, not?

Answer (score -1):

Solved

as simple as that

```
 private async void ContinuousWebRequest()
    {
        while (_keepPolling)
        {
            timeLabel.Text = "call: "+counter+" "+ await RequestTimeAsync()+Environment.NewLine;
            // Update the UI (because of async/await magic, this is still in the UI thread!)
            if (_keepPolling)
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            }
        }
    }

    static async Task<string> RequestTimeAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var jsonString = await client.GetStringAsync("http://date.jsontest.com/");
            var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
            TimePage.counter++;
            return jsonObject["time"].Value<string>();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the down vote. It seems a perfectly acceptable way of doing it.

Comment: @nmdias maybe because original quesion uses device.timer and it doesnt answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

or you can try this:

```
static async Task<string> RequestTimeAsync()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var jsonString = await client.GetStringAsync("http://date.jsontest.com/");
        var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
        return jsonObject["time"].Value<string>();
    }
}


protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    var Text = await RequestTimeAsync();

    Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () => { 
        // i want the taks to be put 
        //here so that it gets repeated
        var jsonDateTsk = RequestTimeAsync();
        jsonDateTsk.Wait();
        var jsonTime = jsonDateTsk.Result;
        var number = float.Parse(Text) - 1;
        var btnText = $"{number}";
        return number > 0;
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple clock demonstrates a one second timer action:

```
       Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), doitt);
        bool doitt()
        {
            label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss");
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (which is how to use async/await in the timer's callback).